# Disable/remove css3 transitions after :active psuedo-class

Tags: css, css-transitions, pseudo-class

So I have a typical scenario: a button styled to transition its colour when hovered over using the :hover psuedo-class.
The button also has a :active triggered class, so that it changes colour again when clicked on; but this time I don't want a transition, so this class has all transitions disabled (I want the change to be snappy).

The problem I have is that whilst this works for the mousedown part of a click, it doesn't for the mouseup part because the :active state is no longer present once the mouse button has been released, and this causes the transitions (that are part of the class definition for the button) to apply.

Is there a way of getting this to work such that hover in/out applies a change with a transition but click down/up does not?
I could probably redo the behaviours in jQuery; but ideally I'd like to achieve this without resorting to JavaScript.

A working example is [here](http://codepen.io/raad/pen/yjIdr).

Thanks.

Comment: I realise my question and example use the background colour to illustrate the problem, and that may have been slightly misleading because it's not the only property I wish to handle in this way, e.g. top/left position, border-color are others.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a trick

for instance, you can change the color, not with the background, but with a shadow:

```
button:active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px green;
}
```

then, the only remaining change that you is to limit the transition to background-color, instead of all

```
button {
    transition: background-color 1s;
}
```

Not really what you wanted, but as close as I can get :-)

Comment: Whilst it doesn't solve all my requirements, it has got me thinking about how I might restructure things to just transition certain props, leaving the rest. Will post an update once tested.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with only CSS by adding different transitions to the active button state and the base button state.

- Add a transition of none to the base button, which means that a transition to the base state will be instant.
- Then, add the desired transition to the button, which means that a transition to the active state (mouse down) will take time.

Here's some example CSS: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hEmbl

```
button {
  background:#009;
  color:#fff;
  padding:1em;
  border:0;
  border-radius:4px;
  -webkit-transition:none;
}

button:active {
  background:#090;
  -webkit-transition:all 1s;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is to use the `:focus` pseudo to keep your green 'state' active:

```
button:active, button:focus {
  transition: none;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 100px green;
  /*background-color: #00f;*/
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tgJcf

NOTE: This works in IE11 and newest Webkit/Blink version(s), but not Firefox, at the time of this writing. Firefox does keep the active state of the button and is probably bugged there.